# How to call listener in Ruby rspec to generate a run time report

Tags: ruby, rspec, selenium-webdriver

Could any one please help me out how to write a code of listener in ruby and rspec

i want to use this listener

```
class MyStoryListener 
  def run_started(number_of_scenarios); end 
  def story_started(story, narrative); end 
  def story_ended(story, narrative); end 
  def scenario_started(story, scenario); end 
  def scenario_succeeded(story, scenario); end 
  def scenario_pending(story, scenario, error); end 
  def scenario_failed(story, scenario, error); end 
  def run_ended; end 
end
```

Comment: It is not clear where you are stuck. It is unlikely that someone will have time to write a whole tutorial from scratch for you, so could you take some time to show what you know already, perhaps with a small piece of test code? Then someone answering only has to give you the missing part

Comment: i want to use this listner 

class MyStoryListener
  def run_started(number_of_scenarios); end
  def story_started(story, narrative); end
  def story_ended(story, narrative); end
  def scenario_started(story, scenario); end
  def scenario_succeeded(story, scenario); end
  def scenario_pending(story, scenario, error); end
  def scenario_failed(story, scenario, error); end
  def run_ended; end
end

Comment: You should edit the question to add those details. I have done that for you this time. I am still not clear where you are stuck. The listener code looks like valid Ruby. What is stopping you from using it?

Comment: Actually i already implemented one testNGprogress plugin in testNg, here we are using ITestListener, same thing i need to implement in ruby with rspec is a unit testing framework of ruby, so i want to tell you how to implement a listner and which listner i call in rspec ,because i am stuckig on two type of listner in rspec (MyStoryListener ,Class: RSpec::Core::Reporter) , thats why i need to help ,how to call listner in rspec, because i am new in ruby

Answer (score 1):

Use `RSpec::Core::Reporter.register_listener(my_story_listener)`.

See http://rdoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Reporter#register_listener-instance_method for details.

A more complete tutorial can be found at http://benmabey.com/2008/07/04/global-setup-in-rspec-or-how-to-add-logging-for-specs.html but note that it's a post from 2008, so the API may have changed since then.